# A way of typing multiple commands in cmd.txt file using PuTTY batch against Cisco

Tags: batch-file, ssh, command, putty, cisco

I am running batch file in Windows environment using PuTTY.exe command below:

```
for /L %%n in (1,1,5) do (
SET z=Site%%n%
start c:\Users\emrpocadmin\desktop\putty.exe -ssh IPAddress -l User -pw Password -m c:\Users\emrpocadmin\desktop\cmds.txt -load Site%%n% 
)
```

This batch should load variable profiles (`n` from 1 to 5) predefined in PuTTY and run on them one-by-one the commands defined in `cmds.txt` file; then save the output to certain folder..

However, in `cmds.txt` file i could only enter one command!

How can I enter multiple commands on this txt file and it should be passed to the session one by one and then save the whole output results into the output file?

I tried to enter the commands on `cmds.txt` file as of below formats but does not work:

```
show run                 (work as one command only)
show run; show version   (does not work)
"show run; show version" (does not work)
echo show run
echo show version        (does not work)
```

The expected result is to enter two or more commands in `cmds.txt` file and it should be passed to the session one by one and then save the whole output results into the output file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a known limitation of Cisco, that it does not support multiple commands in an SSH "exec" channel command.

Quoting section [3.8.3.6 `-m`: read a remote command or script from a file](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#using-cmdline-m) of PuTTY/Plink manual:

> With some servers (particularly Unix systems), you can even put multiple lines in this file and execute more than one command in sequence, or a whole shell script; but this is arguably an abuse, and cannot be expected to work on all servers. **In particular, it is known *not* to work with certain ‘embedded’ servers, such as Cisco routers.**

---

Using [Plink (PuTTY command-line connection tool)](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter7.html) with an input redirection may solve the problem (you should not use PuTTY to automate command execution anyway).

```
plink.exe -ssh IPAddress -l User -pw Password -load Site%%n% < cmds.txt
```