# Hard Time Keeping JSCH Session Alive

Tags: java, jsch

I am trying to run a sequence of commands on a CSICO router using JSCH and SSH. But the problem I am having is after executing the first command, the second one just doesn't execute. The session seems to go down after running the first command. It throws this exception:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Packet corrupt
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.start_discard(Session.java:1067)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.read(Session.java:937)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:309)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
    at com.att.ncaas.device.connection.ssh.SSHConnectionJSch.connect(SSHConnectionJSch.java:120)
```

The code look likes this:

```
public void connect () {

    ChannelExec channelExec = null;
    JSch jSch = new JSch();
    Session session = null;

    try {

        session = jSch.getSession(userid, ipAddress, port);

        // Set the password.
        session.setPassword("XXXXXXXXX");

        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");

        // Set the Ciphers.
        /*
         * properties.put("cipher.s2c", "aes128-cbc"); properties.put("cipher.c2s",
         * "aes128-cbc"); properties.put("CheckCiphers", "aes128-cbc");
         */

        session.setConfig(properties);

        // Finally make the connection.
        session.connect();

        channelExec = (ChannelExec) session.openChannel("exec");

        // Command 1
        channelExec.setCommand("show run");

        ByteArrayOutputStream responseStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

        channelExec.setOutputStream(responseStream);

        channelExec.connect();

        while (channelExec.isConnected()) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        String responseString = new String(responseStream.toByteArray());

        System.out.println("Show Run Output:\n");
        System.out.println(responseString);

        if (session.isConnected()) {
            System.out.println("Wooooooooooooooooooohoooooooooooooooooooooooo!!!!");
        } else {
            session.connect();
        }

        // Command 2
        channelExec.setCommand("show version");

        channelExec.connect();

        while (channelExec.isConnected()) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }

        responseString = new String(responseStream.toByteArray());

        System.out.println("Show Version Output:\n");
        System.out.println(responseString);

    } catch (JSchException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } finally {

        if (session != null) {
            session.disconnect();
        }

        if (channelExec != null) {
            channelExec.disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

When it comes for the second `session.connect()` inside the `if` block, it throws the error. The only other thing I noticed is the when I put the ciphers in, this part:

```
// Set the Ciphers.
properties.put("cipher.s2c", "aes128-cbc");
properties.put("cipher.c2s", "aes128-cbc");
properties.put("CheckCiphers", "aes128-cbc");
```

I get a different error on the same line. I get:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Session.connect: java.io.IOException: End of IO Stream Read
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:565)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:183)
```

Any pointers on how to keep the session alive between two `ChannelExec` execute would really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot reuse the "exec" channel this way. You have to open a new channel for the new command.

---

And note that Cisco is known not to support multiple commands in one "exec" channel, even if specified together upfront:
[Error passing multiple commands to Cisco CLI via plink](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28504014/850848)
I would not be surprised if it did not support multiple "exec" channels in one connection either.

*Did you test with an SSH client, if it is even possible, to do what you are trying to implement?*

Comment: By SSH Client, do you mean something like Putty?

Comment: Yes, PuTTY, OpenSSH – whatever client that can open multiple channels over one connection.

Comment: Yes I wasn't able to get that done. My only option now is to do it via channel shell, if I am to understand correctly. Am I correct there?

Comment: What you were not able to get done? The PuTTY test? Or using multiple "exec" channels in one SSH connection using Paramiko?

Comment: The Putty test. I haven't tried Paramiko. From the looks of things, that seems to be a python tool, which I am not looking for. My main objective is to open a connection to CISCO router, run a few commands, and capture their outputs. I am a bit stumped here. Opening a shell is an option, but waiting for prompts does seem to tricky with it! I looked at a lot of examples, most of them are with one command. I am also exploring other other packages, like J2SSH Maverick and all at the moment.

Comment: But considering what you have given me till now. I guess I can select it as the answer. As it does clearly define what I can and cannot do with the `exec` channel.

Comment: Sorry, I've mistaken the question for different one. Of course, I've meant if you have tried multiple "exec" channels in JSch.